# How to exclude Spring beans by varargs (program arguments) conditional?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How can I let spring evaluate `varargs` and run beans conditionally?

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
  }
}

@Service
@Order(1) //run if no vararg is given
public class Job1 implements ApplicationRunner {
}

@Service
@Order(2) //TODO run only if a "job2" occurs as vararg
public class Job2 implements ApplicationRunner {
}
```

Question: I want to start those jobs conditionally by `varargs` given from command line on application start. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

How about you use `@ConditionalOnProperty` on those beans and you pass the property to include/exclude them from the command line?

A full example could be:

```
@Service
@Order(1) //run if no vararg is given
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "my.property", havingValue = "job1")
public class Job1 implements ApplicationRunner {
}

@Service
@Order(2) //TODO run only if a "job2" occurs as vararg
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "my.property", havingValue = "job2")
public class Job2 implements ApplicationRunner {
}
```

and then you pass the property with:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--my.property=job1/job2"
```

Another option could be removing @Component/@Service from the Job1/Job2 classes and in a configuration class creating a bean like:

```
@Bean
public ApplicationRunner applicatinRunner(ApplicationArguments arguments) throws IOException {
        String commandLineArgument = arguments.getSourceArgs()[0];
        //your logic here to decide which one you want to instantiate
        return new Job1()/Job2();
}
```

Comment: That might work, but I'd have to prefer normal (old style) command line arguments

Comment: If I may, what difference is it gonna make? it's still a command line argument. Just trying to understand what you are aiming to.

Comment: This is certainly a good solution when using spring-style command line args. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible by simply implementing a custom `Condition` and evaluating `ApplicationArguments`. The arguments I was looking for are called **non-optional args** by Spring:

```
class Job2Condition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return context.getBeanFactory()
                .getBean(ApplicationArguments.class)
                .getNonOptionArgs()
                .contains("job2");
    }
}

@Component
@Conditional(Job2Condition.class)
public class Job2 implements ApplicationRunner {
}
```

Comment: Another option could be removing the @Component/@Service annotation and creating a Bean returning an `ApplicationRunner` and getting `ApplicationArguments arguments` as parameter, do your logic in there and programatically return Job1 or Job2.

Comment: That's also a great idea! Though for my case I like the annotation based approach more.